# sharing laptop, 2 VPN clients, but only one GUI

Tags: vpn, windows-10

The problem is that 2 people are sharing one laptop running windows-10, so they want to use VPN (different software, one is CISCO the other I dont know) but there is only one GUI on the laptop. So one connection is fine, but the other does not show the screen/GUI. Any advice?

Comment: I think you need to explain your scenario in some more detail, because I have no idea what you're asking. I'm also rather unsure it's related to security at all.

Comment: Thanks, I will try,

Comment: One laptop running windows 10 is accessed by 2 people. Each using different software; one person uses CISCO to vpn at work, the other person uses another vpn software to connect to work. I would like to know:

Comment: first, is it possible to have 2 GUIs to display each vpn session, not necessarily at the same time.

Comment: and  is it safe at all? if I indeed manage to have 2 vpn sessions (which I cannot at the moment cause my laptop only has one GUI for display) , is information safe?

Comment: @melina: Safe against what? Definitely not if both users don't trust each other since both have physical access to the laptop.

Comment: not fully defined question, it's dependent on the system configuration or software, etc. seems like a very specific support question.